# Persistir todos os dados como string é um problema?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tipagem, tipo-de-conteúdo

Existe algum problema em armazenar todas as informações de uma aplicação como *string* no banco de dados?

Independente da aplicação, do SGDB, da linguagem de programação usada, etc. Eu pergunto mais por questões de tratamento dos dados, na maioria das linguagens que uso manipular strings é mais fácil.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É. Não há como só manipular *string*. Na verdade se fizer isso vai ser mais difícil já que terá que fazer conversões o tempo todo. A não ser que tenha alguma coisa que realmente só trabalhe com texto, o que é pouco provável.

Como você fará contas com *string*? Não dá.

Mas você está no caminho certo se considerar que qualquer informação que não será usada em contas seja do tipo *string*. Um erro comum que programadores iniciantes fazem é armazenar dados que são só números como CEP, CPF, Telefone, etc. como um tipo numérico. Realmente está errado. Descrições devem ser textos, e esses dados são meramente descritivos.

Mas como armazenar dados como quantidade, preço, data de vencimento, etc. como *string*? Isto sim é complicação. Não que não possa fazer mas dará mais trabalho e será mais fácil cometer erros.

Isso vale para o banco de dados ou para o programa propriamente dito. Existem tipos variados por uma boa razão. E na verdade tenho minhas dúvidas se manipular *strings* é mais fácil em alguma linguagem. Não vou afirmar porque acho que seria só minha opinião.

O que está "tentando fazer" é usar uma técnica chamada de *stringly typed* em alusão ao que se chama oficialmente de *strongly typed*. E é abominável.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O ERP da Microsiga cria muitos campos como "string" que deveriam ser numéricos, exemplo Ano do Faturamento , Mês do Faturamento, isto cria dificuldades de toda ordem (validações , classificações etc) , tipos diferentes existem pois existem necessidades diferentes. Manipular números como string é muito trabalhoso.

Comment: @Mota, algumas partes não tem essa gambiarra, adivinha quem fez essas partes? :) E eu faria mais se desse.

Comment: Um exemplo possível (e meio forçado) seria guardar o conteúdo de um arquivo de texto importado, como "lixo" pode ser enviado então datas , valores etc deveriam ser gravados como string.