# Está certo utilizar string quando o valor é inteiro?

Tags: c#, string, int, metodologia

Hoje me deparei com certa situação, que me deixou com duvida:

Em minha aplicação tenho algumas `ID's` vindas de uma tabela, essas `ID's` são valores inteiros (1,2,3, e assim por diante) e todas eu trato elas como `string`.

Uma dos motivos que faço isso é para não utilizar o método: `Convert.Toint` e acabo utilizando o método : `.ToString()`

Não vou realizar nenhuma operação matemática, é somente para identificação de registros (primary key).

Estes `ID's` são obtidos de uma `GridView` populado por um `DataTable` que por sua vez tem os dados vindo do BD, esses `ID's` são gerado pelo banco por uma coluna com `Identity` então nunca teremos valores duplicados.

Também não me interessa se o valor é o primeiro, ultimo, qual é o próximo, é apenas para identificar a ação de exclusão do registro.

Esse tratamento, esta correto? qual a forma indicada nesses casos?

Comment: como vc trata o ID tem a ver com as necessidades da sua aplicação...  se você não tá usando pra nada então nem binda esse valor no objeto da aplicação

Comment: E como você grava esses IDs? Como garante que eles são únicos? Como sabe qual é o próximo? Dê mais contexto.

Comment: pelo oq eu entendi são inteiros que ele trata na aplicação como string... e a dúvida é se esse tratamento tá correto

Comment: @J.Guilherme preciso desses valores, pois ele identifica o registro a ser excluído, e a duvida e essa mesmo, se o tratamento esta correto.

Comment: @bigown fiz uma revisão na pergunta

Comment: O ID do banco de dados é numérico, certo?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136398/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45213/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16967/101.

Comment: @bigown sim, no banco é int, obrigado vou ler essas perguntas, mas essa daqui já ta mais que respondida, se é inteiro trate como inteiro, sem surpresas, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe correto ou errado propriamente dito nesse caso. Existe o indicado e o mais eficiente. Se os campos são inteiros, trate-os como tal. Pode parecer que não tenha qualquer coisa o impedindo de usar os inteiros convertidos para string nessa situação, mas existe uma "regra" em desenvolvimento de sistemas que costumo seguir com muito sucesso: **Faça a coisa menos surpreendente. Sempre.**

Surpreendente, no caso, deve ser lido como "algo que gere menos surpresa".

Nesse caso, se o campo é inteiro (ou `long`) no banco de dados, trate-o como tal no seu código também. Isso gerará menos surpresa a algum outro programador, ou até à você mesmo quando vier resolver um bug no código daqui a alguns anos. Ademais, usar `Convert.ToInt32()` no lugar de `ToString()` não terá qualquer diferença, mas apenas o fato de você se perguntar se tratar o inteiro como string no seu código é o certo, já mostra que o ideal seria nem precisar fazer essa pergunta e tratar inteiro como o inteiro que é.

Te garanto também que no `DataTable` esse campo é inteiro. Se for comparar o ID do GridView com o id no dataset/datatable, pode vir a ter que converter de volta para inteiro de qualquer

Há ainda funcionalidades futuras que possam ser afetadas por essa conversão desnecessária feita hoje. Por exemplo, você pode vir a precisar colocar os Ids dentro de um `Hashset` e se forem strings as operações serão mais lentas (não muito, pois o Hashset usa um hash para ser encontrado, mas há perda de performance). Você pode querer ordenar os Ids para saber qual foi criado antes no banco de dados (já que é identity) e a ordenação de strings, além de muito mais lenta, não segue a ordem numérica: `"10" < "2"` enquanto que `10 > 2`.

Resumindo: enquanto existem motivos para usar inteiro como inteiro, com vantagens, não existem vantagens nem motivos (no seu caso) de tratá-los como string.

Não pregue peças em si mesmo (e nos outros que usem seu código). Faça o que gere menos surpresa. Se pergunte: O que é o mais esperado? Que um campo inteiro no banco seja tratado como string no seu código, ou que seja tratado como inteiro mesmo?

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de você não utilizar as IDs para operações matemáticas, você certamente faz comparacoes, principalmente na busca de dados no seu banco. Pensando em performance, a melhor pratica ainda e utilizar numeros, pois as comparacoes podem ser feitas em um ciclo, ao passo que comparacao de strings requer que cada caractere seja comparado (a menos que voce converta para numeros).
Com relacao a sua preocupacao de chamar ToString repetidamente, pode ficar tranquilo, pois este metodo e muito rapido e otimizado a nivel da CLR, entao jamais sera o bottleneck em nenhuma aplicacao. O que poderia ser um problema e o boxing e unboxing dos valores, ou seja, deixando que o C# faca o trabalho pra voce.

Por exemplo, o codigo

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    sb.Append(i.ToString()); 
    sb.Append(",");
}
```

é mais rapido do que

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
    sb.Append (i + ",");
```

Justamente porque o segundo requer operacoes de boxing e unboxing extras.

Desta forma, faz mais sentido se preocupar com a eficiencia da busca no seu banco e outras comparacoes entre as IDs do que com ToString, o que significa que, no geral, int seria uma escolha melhor.

Comment: Você mediu a performance dos dois casos usando uma quantidade alta de iterações? Pode se surpreender... Sem falar que provavelmente ocorre boxing nos dois casos, já que para chamar `ToString` tem que ser tratado como object... Mas teria que ver o IL de ambos os casos.

Comment: Sim. Este exemplo eh conhecido, tirei do livro c# in a nutshell. Existe uma pergunta desse exemplo no SO tbm onde a pessoa explica mais afundo a diferenca. Quando voce chama ToString em um tipo, por exemplo i.ToString, onde i é um inteiro, voce pula a parte do boxing porque a informacao ja e conhecida. Voce pode ver na IL gerada pelo compilador. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293932/c-why-does-tostring-append-text-faster-to-an-int-converted-to-string

Comment: Na verdade o que ocorre então é uma otimização do compilador. Por isso queira ver o IL gerado e, novamente, tem que testar a performance, uma vez que o otimizador pode muito bem evitar o boxing desnecessário. Ainda há o caso de haver uma chamada de método a mais no segundo exemplo. Concordo com você sobre o hit de performance com operações de boxing e unboxing, mas não acredito que o exemplo específico resulte em código mais lento, pois não isola o problema do boxing/unboxing. Mais tarde meço ambos os métodos.

Comment: Fiz os testes de performance e, inclusive, comentei na resposta no Stack Overflow em inglês. O grande culpado da perda de performance nesse exemplo é o `string.Concat()` que acaba ocorrendo no primeiro exemplo e que não acontece no segundo. Isso dá uma diferença de uns 30ms em 1 milhão de iterações. Se mudarmos o código para forçar o boxing, mas deixarmos separados em duas chamadas ao `sb.Append()` essa diferença cai para 5ms. Ou seja, você está certo, tem um impacto negativo, mas o maior impacto nesses exemplos não é do boxing!